# How to write keywords beside the keyword heading?

Tags: overleaf, keywords

I am trying to write the keywords beside the keyword heading but not getting it correctly. I had also mentioned it in the image attached here[image]

```
\documentclass[suppldata]{interact}
\begin{document}
\begin{keywords}
BAN,IoT,IoHT,Personal Health Record, Standardization, Protocols
\end{keywords}
\end{document}
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where can we find the class `interact`, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: a]

Try this code. Uses the new environment `keywordsinline` based on the original `keywords` environment

```
    \documentclass[suppldata]{interact}

\newenvironment{keywordsinline}{%
    \par\addvspace{13pt plus2pt minus1pt}
    \keywordfont\noindent{\bfseries \keywordsname:\ }\ignorespaces%
}{\par\addvspace{13pt plus2pt minus1pt}     }

\begin{document}
    \begin{keywordsinline}
        BAN,IoT,IoHT,Personal Health Record, Standardization, Protocols
    \end{keywordsinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir....Its working fine....